# macOs "env: python3: No such file or directory " when executing script with plist

Tags: python, macos, path, plist

I have built a simple web scraper script `scraper.py` using `python 3.6` which runs just fine when I executing from the terminal. Now I would like to run it automatically when logging into my computer, so I wrote a simple `scraper_launcher.plist` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"    "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
   <key>Label</key>
   <string>scraper.job</string>
   <key>ProgramArguments</key>
   <array>
      <string>./Users/me/Desktop/scraperFolder/scraper.py</string>
   </array>
   <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
   <string>Users/me/Library/Logs/Errors/scraper.error</string>
   <key>KeepAlive</key>
   <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

in my `Users/me/Library/LaunchAgents/` folder.

The first problem I encounter is that when executing `launchctl load scraper_launcher.plist` macOs seem to use `python 2.7` by default and the script fails. In order to solve this problem I tried adding at the beginning of `scraper.py` the shabang specifying the python version: `#!/usr/bin/env python3`.

Now when I execute `./scraper.py` on my terminal everything still works fine, but when I do `launchctl load scraper_launcher.plist` I get the following error:

`env: python3: No such file or directory`.

What am I missing? I have a `macOS High Sierra v10.13.6`.

PS: Of course I could recode `scraper.py` into `python 2.7` but that is not the point, I would like to have it work as it is and understand why scraper_launcher.plist is giving such error.

Comment: Launch agents are run directly by `launchd`, not by a shell, and hence don't have whatever customizations you have in your shell init files, like additions to `PATH`. You can add an `EnvironmentVariables` dictionary including `PATH`, or use an explicit path in the shebang.

Comment: Thanks @GordonDavisson, I solved the issue as you said adding the explicit path to python3 in the shebang